# what glue can be used between 2 failed floating luxury vinyl planks

Tags: vinyl-flooring

After 10 months my floating luxury vinyl planks are beginning to come apart. I have removed and replaced them to no avail. As a last resort, I would like to glue them to each other- not to the floor. Can anyone tell me the best glue to use for this? I'm looking at Eurobond D3 but I'm afraid it isn't good with luxury vinyl.  I would so appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Need some pictures and brand of planks.   Also what makes vinyl planks luxury?

Comment: Those planks will grow and shrink with temperature changes so gluing may give you problems.

Comment: superglue plus hardener.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the floor underneath the planks causing the problems?  Most of those planks like a flat floor, bumps, legos will cause problem.